# get width with php return height

Tags: php, image

i had a image on a apache server with php, when i try to get the width of a image the funcion return the height.

```
Array
(
    [0] => 640
    [1] => 480
    [2] => 2
    [3] => width="640" height="480"
    [bits] => 8
    [channels] => 3
    [mime] => image/jpeg
)
```

and the image had height=640 and width=480

http://159.203.81.222/upload/redimensionar.php

In that server i had the code and can watch the image what i'm trying to get the value.

i don't what is wrong, the code what i use is:

```
<?php
$size = getimagesize('../media/original/1.jpg');
print_r($size);
?>
```

Some help?

Comment: jpg can have a "rotate to display" flag. your image viewer may be honoring that and showing the picture in X/Y format, even though the on-disk bytes are in Y/X orientation. getimagesize isn't wrong, it's your image viewer that's "lying" to you by trying to be helpful.

Comment: in my computer, browser and editor is the same :(

Comment: I know that firefox honors the rotation flag, so take that as you will.

Comment: so, how i can determine that? cuz when i use the img tag the image is oriented bad :/. if i upload the image to facebook show good but i can't do it. sorry for my english and thanks you for your time :)

Comment: I upload a photo taked with another mobile, the problem is my cellphone cuz is a iPhone, maybe some data is different and the library is not update. tty for your help.

Comment: <img src="link" />